# create indexes for search using MongoTemplate?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, full-text-indexing, mongotemplate

how we can create `Indexes` for the following query using `MongoTemplate`? I am referring to site http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/search-for-text/ they've not given any details about how we can create Indexes using MongoTemplate?

```
db.getCollection('user').ensureIndex({ firstName: "text", middleName : 
"text", lastName : "text",emailId:"text" });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose your entity `User` is modelled as

```
@Document
class User {
    String firstName;
    String middleName;
    String lastName;
    String emailId;
}
```

and want to have a text index based on its firstName, middleName, lastName and emailId fields, the raw MongoDB index definition would look something like this:

```
 { 
    firstName: "text", 
    middleName: "text", 
    lastName: "text",
    emailId: "text" 
}
```

To **[create a text index](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.index-and-collections.index)** on the fields above you want to have full text search enabled on, do the following

```
TextIndexDefinition textIndex = new TextIndexDefinitionBuilder()
    .onField("firstName")
    .onField("middleName")
    .onField("lastName")
    .onField("emailId")
    .build();

MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(new Mongo(), "database"); // obtain MongoTemplate
mongoTemplate.indexOps(User.class).ensureIndex(textIndex);
```

Or you can create the index automatically through mapping annotations:

```
@Document
class User {
    @TextIndexed String firstName;
    @TextIndexed String middleName;
    @TextIndexed String lastName;
    @TextIndexed String emailId;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Easiest way to create indexes in mongo using spring Java will be:

```
// Define ur mongo template defination

DBObject indexOptions = new BasicDBObject();
indexOptions.put("a", 1);
indexOptions.put("b", 1);
indexOptions.put("c.d", 1);
indexOptions.put("e.f", 1);
CompoundIndexDefinition indexDefinition =
            new CompoundIndexDefinition(indexOptions);
mongoTemplate.indexOps(<Classname>.class).ensureIndex(indexDefinition);
```

A unique index can be configured on the index definition:
`mongoTemplate.indexOps(<Classname>.class).ensureIndex(indexDefinition.unique());`

Answer (score 0):

In spring mongodb 2.0.1

```
    TextIndexDefinition textIndex = new TextIndexDefinition.TextIndexDefinitionBuilder().onField(indexName).build();

    mongoTemplate.indexOps(DINMonitorLog.class).ensureIndex(textIndex);
```